# How to override server.xml for Atlassian SDK?

Tags: jira-plugin, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I installed the **Atlassian SDK 6.3.12**.
Now I am developing a plugin for Jira.

And issued with problem, that **I can't change the server.xml for tomcat8x** (located in target plugin folder).
Because every start of `atlas-debug` or `atlas-run` this file is overwritten.

#### How to use custom server.xml?

---

*P.S. motivation: [Changing server.xml to handle requests with special characters](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/changing-server-xml-to-handle-requests-with-special-characters-958453799.html)*

Comment: The link you have mentioned is appropriate for installable Jira instance not for plugin jira instance, because plugin jira instance will always overwrite most of the files on startup.

Comment: The actual question is: what do you really want to achieve? Because as soon as you've developed your plugin and installed it on your customer's Jira servers, you also can't change their server.xml files.

Comment: @s.hesse I want solve problem with tomcat which I faced during plugin development. In logs I see exception about parsing headers. So almost no one link is working. Reinstalling of SDK didn't help. Jira version in plugin 7.9.0 (8.0.0 works well).

Comment: Also I tried SDK 8.0.7, the same. Create software project, then issue. Then try to assign – caught message "jira cloud (sic!) communication breakdown" (smth like that). In logs – exception about parsing request headers.

Comment: `INFO: Error parsing HTTP request header
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986`

Comment: Ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @boileau Actually no.